# Why is my discord.js bot not reacting to images/media?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This discord bot is made to react to images/media in any #meme channels however, it doesn't react to any media. But there are no errors in the code and it boots up just fine and logs everything fine. what could be the issue?

```
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const TOKEN = ""


const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions
  ],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  console.log(`message sent in ${message.channel.name}`);
  if (
    message.channel.name === 'memes' &&
    message.attachments.size > 0 &&
    message.attachments.some((attachment) => {
      const validExtensions = ['.mp4', '.gif', '.jpg', '.png', '.webm'];
      return validExtensions.some((ext) => attachment.url.endsWith(ext));
    })
  ) {
    message.react('⭐');
  }
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Can you share sample output of what *does* happen when you run this and a valid media item is added? When you say "*it[...] logs everything fine*", should we take that explicitly to mean that you *do* indeed see the message logged by the line `console.log(\`message sent in ${message.channel.name}\`);`? Can you add a log line afterward to print the contents of the object key/values you're using in your `if` statement? For example, `console.log(message.channel.name, message.attachments.size, message.attachments);`

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with u using `attachment.url.endsWith()` function. Discords output for any attachment will result in something like proxyUrl.
For example, my file's name is: `politechnika-slaska.jpg`. Its attachment.url is: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/id1/id2/politechnika-slaska.jpg?ex=6596c97f&is=6584547f&hm=66a344d1f59052292398b1933b883e6ded28b5f83e4f2b2a3f01e5cbc4c795e3&
So, as you see, it doesn't end with any extension. What you should do, is change the attachment.url to attachment.name, then it works fine, because attachment.name is a whole name used from the input file, in my example: `politechnika-slaska.jpg`. You can see it when I'm outputting it as `console.log()` in last if statement.

You can test it by putting some console logs into that code:

```js
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
  ],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  console.log(`message sent in ${message.channel.name}`);
  console.log(message.channel.name === "admin-channel");
  console.log(message.attachments.size > 0);
  console.log(
    message.attachments.some((attachment) => {
      const validExtensions = [".mp4", ".gif", ".jpg", ".png", ".webm"];
      return validExtensions.some((ext) => attachment.url.endsWith(ext));
    })
  );
  if (
    message.channel.name === "admin-channel" &&
    message.attachments.size > 0 &&
    message.attachments.some((attachment) => {
      const validExtensions = [".mp4", ".gif", ".jpg", ".png", ".webm"];
      console.log(attachment);
      return validExtensions.some((ext) => attachment.name.endsWith(ext));
    })
  ) {
    console.log("message is valid");
    message.react("⭐");
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

I'm using token from config.json file, so you should change that accordingly to your code.